# How should I handle m4 make error "Please port gnulib freading.c to your platform!"?

Tags: gnu-make, m4

Long story short, I'm on Kali rolling 2021.3 and I'm trying to build bison and bison requires m4. [I followed this](https://geeksww.com/tutorials/libraries/m4/installation/installing_m4_macro_processor_ubuntu_linux.php) and someone else had the same problem as I am. But while building m4, I'm getting:

```
freading.c:44:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freading.c to your platform!"
```

Here's all my steps with m4 and some truncated output from making m4:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.10.tar.gz
```

Untar and cd in to extracted directory:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/m4
make
```

Then receiving this output(I added the number lines):

```
68  } | sed '/""/d' > configmake.h-t
69  mv configmake.h-t configmake.h
70  make  all-am
71  make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kali/Downloads/m4-1.4.10/lib'
72  gcc  -I.     -g -O2 -MT freading.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/freading.Tpo -c -o freading.o freading.c
73  freading.c: In function ‘freading’:
74  freading.c:44:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freading.c to your platform!"
75     44 |  #error "Please port gnulib freading.c to your platform!"
76        |   ^~~~~
77  make[2]: *** [Makefile:598: freading.o] Error 1
78  make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kali/Downloads/m4-1.4.10/lib'
79  make[1]: *** [Makefile:451: all] Error 2
80  make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kali/Downloads/m4-1.4.10/lib'
81  make: *** [Makefile:421: all-recursive] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how I should handle this kind of error, especially around m4?

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of m4?  The version you're using was released in 2008 and probably doesn't know about newer systems.

Comment: @MadScientist OK I'll go back and see if I can do that. I needed to aim low on m4 version so that I can build the old bison, so I can build libpcap (since the rolling Kali glibc is too old, there was a problem building libpcap with the new Bison), so that I can build fragroute because they took fragroute out of kali rolling last year